# WebAPI POST without data causes application to crash

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have a simple OWIN self-hosted application with a controller extending `ApiController`. The problem is, when I send a POST request with no data to the controller (the method doesn't have parameters), it returns:

> Length Required

And then the application crashes with an unhandled `ObjectDisposedException` (full stack trace below). If the POST request contains data then all is well.

I removed all controller logic from the equation by replicating with this simple method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void MyMethod()
{
    return;
}
```

Therefore I'm guessing it's something to do with routing? But my routes are only set up as the default:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("My Service", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Why would my application be behaving in this manner?

To send the requests I use `curl`:

```
curl --request POST http://localhost/mycontroller/mymethod
```

Stack trace:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a
>   disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.HttpListenerResponse'.   at
>   System.Net.HttpListenerResponse.set_StatusCode (System.Int32 value)
>   [0x00016] in <59be416de143456b88b9988284f43350>:0    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.RequestProcessing.OwinHttpListenerResponse.End
>   () [0x0001c] in <5086711574984403b242554b11c41440>:0    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.RequestProcessing.OwinHttpListenerContext.End
>   () [0x00010] in <5086711574984403b242554b11c41440>:0    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.RequestProcessing.OwinHttpListenerContext.End
>   (System.Exception ex) [0x0001e] in
>   <5086711574984403b242554b11c41440>:0    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener+d__5.MoveNext
>   () [0x001f9] in <5086711574984403b242554b11c41440>:0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in :0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0004e] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.OwinHttpListener+d__0.MoveNext
>   () [0x00202] in <5086711574984403b242554b11c41440>:0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in :0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.m__1
>   (System.Object state) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context
>   (System.Object state) [0x0000e] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state,
>   System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x0008d] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
>   (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state,
>   System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem
>   () [0x0002a] in :0    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00096] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback ()
>   [0x00000] in :0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you show all your controller class I can help you a little more.

Try to make your post like this.

Make one class every get/post

for example in folder Controllers/Api/MyFunction.cs

in WebApiConfig.cs

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "API/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

in your "MyFunction.cs"

```
public class MyFunction : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
    public bool Post(string param1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```